# Any way to access values in a tuple?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, tuples

I was wondering if there was any way to access a value in a tuple?

for example:

```
a = [('ANTA01H3F', 'LEC02', '17-12-07', '14:00')]
```

and i wanted just '17-12-07' and '14:00'.  Is there a way i can get these values and attach them to a string.

```
print("The date is" + '17-12-07' + " and time is" + '14:00')
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's not that difficult.

Comment: i tried to do something like you would do for a list. Such as date = a[2] or time = a[3]

Comment: it is not tuple - it is list with tuple inside. `date = a[0][2]`

Comment: `a[0][2]` for date, `a[0][3]` for time. You need to see that you have a list with only one element (the tuple) and that element has 4 other elements in it.

Answer (score 4):

```
a = [('ANTA01H3F', 'LEC02', '17-12-07', '14:00')]
```

It is not tuple - it is list with one element - tuple

To get value you have to use two indexes

```
date = a[0][2]
```

This is tuple

```
a = ('ANTA01H3F', 'LEC02', '17-12-07', '14:00')

date = a[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack the tuple, then print using string format:

```
a = [('ANTA01H3F', 'LEC02', '17-12-07', '14:00')]
_, _, date, time = a[0]
print(f"The date is {date} and time is {time}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access them as you would in a normal list, using indices.
If `tup=(1,2,3)` then `tup[1]` is 2